# String array in query parameters swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I'm working on a project where there is an endpoint that receives a list of strings in the parameter, as shown in the code below:

```
public class PaymentFilter
{
    public List<string> Status  {get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] PaymentFilter filter)
{
    ...
}
```

However, in the swagger interface the status list is not reflected, as shown in the image:

[image]

How do I enable entries for the status list?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking but to enter values for the array in swagger click "Try it out" then "Add string item"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click `Try it out` button and click `Add string item` then you can add
parameter

[image]

Comment: I am using dotnet core 3.1 with Swashbuckle and when I use the same type ([FromQuery] List<string> ids) of param, I don't see it returning as a list of strings but as the comma-separated single string value. Any idea? Btw, tested this out with v6.1 and it works just fine.  Not sure if its a bug with package..

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to comma separated list problem sir?